# spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier How to import a static method into groovy DSL contract file within same project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

While defining the producer side contract in resources/contract.groovy, i am unable to import a java util class with a static method. It throws an error that " unable to resolve class ".
I am using this custom validation method in bodyMatchers, byCommand. I know that there is a feature to use a static method from a dependency jar file by adding the dependency in the plugin definition in pom.xml. OR we can define the method in base class.
But can we import a static method that is defined in another class in the same project ?

```
Execution default-generateTests of goal 
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE:generateTests failed: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[ERROR] src/test/resources/contracts/select/contract.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation? You can read about this here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/advanced.html and check out samples here for the producer (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer/pom.xml#L124-L131) and here for the consumer (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/consumer/pom.xml#L90-L95). In general you need to create a JAR with all the additional classes you want to use in your DSL and then you'll have to add that JAR to your plugin's classpath.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. In my project, the util validation method is applicable only for the producer. We are thinking to keep the validation methods (very few) inside the producer test packages. So is there a way this enhancement  to the framework can be considered in future ? I think this is a common scenario and other users might have requested too. Please let me know

Comment: It's not the case of a feature that we could write, it's a problem with maven / gradle requiring things to be there on the classpath for the plugin. That's a different classpath than the one that the project uses.